# Why are Hindu gods portrayed as fallible and flawed like Greek/Roman gods?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, ramayana, gods, vedic-gods

Among the stories from Mahabharat, Ramayana, Purana, etc I have heard, it seems Hindu gods are very fallible - they make mistakes, they commit crimes, they get angry, they harass people, they get cursed by mortal rishis, they get into fights, etc.

Instances I am talking about:

1. Rama talks badly with Sita at the end of Yuddha Kanda and Sita scolds him back. So Rama is not infallible
2. Krishna gets killed at the end of Mahabharat. Krishna also gets defeated by Jarasandha. Strangely, Krishna, the Supreme God, is committing mistakes and is getting defeated.
3. Goddess Kali mistakenly steps of Shiva and bites her tongue in shame
4. Indra has adulterous intercourse with wives of others. Indra, god of gods, disrespects Brihaspati and that is portrayed as a bad thing. So, even gods have to respect mortal men?
5. Numerous instances of gods and rishis ejaculating in front of women, including Shiva and Brahma, part of the Trimurti.
6. Shiva gets angry very quickly despite the fact that he is supposed to be Adi Yogi, the guy who has become one with the Brahman, the most blissful state. How can such a person be angry?
7. Rishis get angry all the time and curses people. Mahabharat has a whole story where Krishna saves Draupadi from the possibility that a sage Durvasa might curse her.

What is going on? I understand about rishis, C Rajagopalachari explains that rishis have always been portrayed as flawed because even the most learned in ethics can make mistakes (even though I don't understand how can people united with the Brahman become angry and make mistakes). Why are gods making mistakes, committing adultery, getting cursed, and so on? Even Trimurti, the supreme gods are not exempt from it. Why? Rajagopalachari in Mahabharat doesn't offer a proper explanation. He says that these stories deliberately portray gods as fallible and flawed but doesn't really mention a reason.

Why Greek/Roman gods were portrayed as fallible and flawed is also beyond me. But they are dead religions and philosophers like Plato have raised issues with these stories. But Hinduism is an alive religion and its Puranic and epic stories do not seem to be condemned or commented by a lot of people (iirc only Swami Vivekanand and Dayanand Saraswati rejected them). Why? Why are gods designed to be flawed in Hinduism? Is the message supposed to be that "Only Brahman is perfect. Gods, like humans, are prone to err"? Or is every single bad act of gods, like Brahma's harassment of Saraswati, all supposed to be symbolical?

Comment: 3,5 and 6 are from puranas. Puranas are not meant to be taken literally. You elucidate it with the help of your imaginative power in a way that will generate devotion in the mind of men for Sri Hari who is the soul and support of all."

Bhagavata Purana II.8.51-52.   ;These narratives are only the literary device I have used with a view to instil into you the importance of renunciation and realisation. They have no ultimate significance in themselves (or are not to be taken as literal facts.)

Srimad Bhagavata Purana XII.3.14

Comment: @Hope I checked Bhagavad Purana 12.3.14. How can you guys be so dishonest? No it doesn't say what you say at all. It says that the stories of KINGS are supposed to instill importance of renunciation and stuff, he never said that the stories regarding him and other gods are not literal. Also, it says that the stories are not to be confused with 'real knowledge' which is Yoga, it doesn't talk about whether they are factual or not. Can't believe people like you are in the forum

Answer (score 2):

1. Rama purposefully blamed Sita to cause the Agni pariksha and show the world that Sita is Pure -

> "I also know that Seetha, the daughter of Janaka, who ever revolves in
> my mind, is undivided in her affection to me. Ravana could not violate
> this wide-eyed woman, protected as she was by her own splendour, any
> more than an ocean would transgress its bounds. **In order to convince
> the three worlds, I, whose refugee is truth, ignored Seetha while she
> was entering the fire.**"

Sarga 118, Yuddha kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.

2. Jarasandha never, ever defeated Lord Krishna. Lord Krishna defeated Jarasandha 18 times but spared his life -

> "**Eighteen times did the haughty prince of Magadhā renew his attack
> upon the Yādavas, headed by Kṛṣṇa; and was as often defeated and put
> to the rout by them, with very inferior numbers.** That the Yādavas were
> not overpowered by their foes, was owing to the present might of the
> portion of the discus-armed Vishnu.”

Book V, Vishnu Purana.

The reason Lord Krishna spared Jarasandha was because Brahma had destined Bhima to be Jarasandha's slayer -

> “And the lord Shouri, supreme among strong ones, with a valour equal
> to that of tigers, also remembered. This did the truthful Achyuta
> remember. **It had been destined that Jarasandha would be killed by the
> valorous Bhima. Madhusudana, the younger brother of Haladhara,
> foremost among those who have controlled themselves, wished to show
> respect to Brahma and did not wish to kill him himself."**

245(20), Jarasandha-vadha parva, Mahabharata.

Krishna left the earth by his own wish. His Avatara purpose was over. There was no point remaining on earth anymore. Jara the hunter was just an excuse to leave.